# Using io.compression.zipFile to unzip multi-part zip file?

Tags: .net, powershell, zip

I'm trying to unzip a large, multi-part zip file with this:

```
Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
$source = "C:\test\sample.zip.001"
$destination = "C:\test\unzipped\"
[io.compression.zipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($source,$destination)
```

This will run for a long time (presumably due to the 5GB size of the zip file), but then throws the error:

> Exception calling "ExtractToDirectory" with "2" argument(s): "End of Central Directory record could not be found."

Do I need to use a different command for a multi-part (split) zip file?

Comment: Have you considered using the 7zip command line utility? It's pretty awesome, and accepts piped input and everything if you use the right switches.

Comment: I have. Interestingly, I can unzip this file just fine from the command line, but when I do it in Powershell, it fails to unzip with an "Unexpected end of archive" with this command:  & cmd.exe /c "c:\program files\7-zip\7z.exe" e $source -o$destination -y    I was going to create a separate post about that one if I can't figure it out soon. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.IO.Compression` use can't handle multipart zip files, the error you're getting means it cannot find the end of the file (because it's in another part).

It's a very basic namespace and the classes in it do not provide control for many other things like passwords, comments, AES encryption, ZIP64 or Unicode.

You'll either need to use a command line zip utility like 7zip or an assembly like [DotNetZip](https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd) that can handle multipart files.

Comment: Thanks, James. I suspected that might be the case. I tried using 7zip's command line program, but ran into a similar problem. I'll tackle that separately.

Comment: Any suggestions for those of us using .NET Core?

Comment: @Yoshiya I'd recommend asking your own question as .net core is quite different to PowerShell.